# google app engine python mail api changing to utf-8 for other language?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
body = """
Welcome %s,
Congratulations, you have just joined us.

Start using our site by click the link below:
%s

We hope that you enjoy!

Team.

恭喜妳/你已成為會員。

%s

希望妳能享受使用！

""".encode('utf-8') % (username, request_url, request_url)


mail.send_mail(sender=sender_address, to=email_address, subject=subject, body=body)
```

Okay here is what I have so far and it doesn't work. What can I do to encode utf-8 to mail api and make it works for using more than one language in the one email?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you imagine "won't work" is supposed to tell us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.encode('utf-8')` makes binary out of the string. You have to use `.decode('utf-8')`
See: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python and also http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it.

One way I found is to send mail through html.

```
ActivationEmailMessage.html = u"""
            <html><head></head><body>
            xxxxxx
            </body></html>
            """.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')

ActivationEmailMessage.send()
```